# UITableView parallax header scroll animation (TuneIn)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll, parallax

I'm not new to iOS development and although not to stackoverflow but I have a question regarding the following picture/animation.

http://postimg.org/image/gbyppuwad/

Does anyone know how this could be done in iOS?

It must be a tableView, since there is a scollbar at the right. Maybe it's a headerView or a customView on top of the tableView and the tableView insets are set .. I really don't know ..

The app is called TuneIn ..

Can anybody help please and bring my sleep back it's bugging me for days.. :D

Comment: Do you found a solution for that. I'm looking for exactly the same..

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not opening in Chrome for some reason, but if you're looking for parallax effect - you basically need to listen to UIScrollViewDelegate in your view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html

There is a method called `scrollViewDidScroll:` which gets called after each content offset changes in the scroll view. You need to implement it and adjust your background view position based on desired algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've fixed the link to the image. It's not just the parallax effect, it's also the scrolling and fixation at the navigationBar. Can you imagine how they solved this?

Comment: The answer would actually be the same. You still need to subscribe to that delegate and do your hiding/moving of other views as user scrolls the table view.